# How to share data for all running Sanic server processes

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, sanic

I need to share a simple object (bytes object) along with all Sanic workers. Does someone know how to do that?
Of course, I know multiprocessing.Array, but how to propagate that through Sanic API to all workers?

Answer (score 1):

This ability does not exist in sanic. You could create an issue and ask if you could add it. You could add a dict using this example code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def proc(d):
  l = d["list"]
  l.append('test')
  d['list'] = l
  print ('subprocess:', d)

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()
d["list"] = []

processes = []
for _ in range(2):
  p = Process(target=proc, args=(d,))
  p.daemon = True
  p.start()
  processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
  process.join()

for process in processes:
  process.terminate()

print ('main process:', d)
```